# How to create an object of SLRequest manually?

Tags: objective-c, twitter

I am using Twitter integration in my app. During fetching follower list from twitter server by sending request of type SLRequest I need a SLRequest object. so want to set account property of SLRequest , but I don't want to configure my device with twitter account. How can I create an object of type ACAccount manually ?